# Will JVM always create instance of Object class

Tags: java, jvm, classloader

suppose with the following code, does JVM always create instance of Object class, since Object is parent for all the classes the in Java.

```
class MyTestclass{

   void printMe(String name){
        System.out.println('I am '+name);
   }
   public static void main(String args[]){
        MyTestclass obj = new MyTestclass();
        obj.printMe("stackOverFlow.com");
   }
}
```

Another class say TestClass2

```
class TestClass2{

   void printMe(String name){
        System.out.println('I am '+name);
   }
   public static void main(String args[]){
        MyTestclass obj = new MyTestclass();
        TestClass2 obj2 = new TestClass2();
        obj.printMe("stackOverFlow.com");
        obj2.printMe("stackOverFlow.com");
   }
}
```

Will JVM creates two object instances if i run these two classes?

Comment: In theory, the JVM can "allocate" objects on the stack, so in fact no objects get created as it effectively unpacks all the fields as local variables. See `-XX:+UseEscapeAnalysis` In practice it rarely does this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. There is only one object created and all the memory allocated in the name of Child, even for the field inherited from Parent.

> does JVM always create instance of Object class, since Object is parent for all the classes the in Java.

No. But instead JVM calls the parent constructors until it reaches the top most Object constructor which calls as [constructor chaining](http://codeinventions.blogspot.com/2014/09/argumented-constructor-constructor-overloading--and-constructor-chaining-in-Java.html).

Answer (score 2):

Well... it depends what you mean by asking whether an instance of `Object` gets created...

Remember how inheritance works. Suppose that you have four classes: `Object`, `Animal`, `Dog` and `Terrier`. When you create an instance of `Terrier`

```
Terrier t = new Terrier();
```

only one instance gets created. You don't get a *separate* `Object` instance created. But on the other hand, the point of inheritance is that a `Terrier` **is** a `Dog`, and it **is** an `Animal`, and it **is** an `Object`. So this one instance that gets created isn't *merely* an `Object`, but it certainly *is* an `Object`, just like everything else.

So you *could* have written

```
Object t = new Terrier();
```

or

```
Animal t = new Terrier();
```

or

```
Dog t = new Terrier();
```

and it would have been perfectly valid Java.

So the answer is: a single instance of a subclass of `Object` gets created, and **it thereby is an `Object`**.

Comment: Yes , I meant how many instances of Object class will be present or created.

Answer (score 1):

Only one object is created no matter what is the inheritance hierarchy is. Features from the parent are inherited and are provided in the object of class that is used with new operator.

```
  MyTestclass obj = new MyTestclass();
```

one object with all the features of `MyTestclass` and `Object` class in `obj` instance.